# progressbar - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the progressbar module but am getting the following error. `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` I am testing the exact snippet from the documentation.

```
import time
import progressbar

for i in progressbar.progressbar(range(100)):
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

Comment: what is the name of script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you have the script name `progressbar.py` as well :) or a folder with the example. Try to rename the folder where you have your test script and the script file if it is named `progressbar`.

One more idea: you are trying to run example for `progressbar2` library but have installed `progressbar` (which is a different package) instead.

Please check packages:
* https://pypi.org/project/progressbar2/
* https://pypi.org/project/progressbar/

> I've just tried your example with installed `progressbar`, it failed with the same error as you have, after that I installed `progressbar2` instead and it works well ;)
>
> ````
> 100% (100 of 100) > |############################################################################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:02 Time:  0:00:02```
> ````

You can list your installed packages and versions using `pip freeze`.

Comment: I did infact have my test file named progressbar.py which I can't believe I did. However after fixing that and even trying a new file in a new directory I am still getting this error

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. You should install both [progressbar](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar/) and [progressbar2](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar2/), and then try to execute your code by [progressbar](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar/) library.